# The arm forward kinematic (FK) doesn't move when I move the arm

Tags: rigging, rigify

I want to move the arms placed straight along the side of the body. Am I doing something wrong if the FK doesn't move with it? Is there a certain piece of the rig I supposed to interact with?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IK bones and FK bones act independently, to go from IK to FK you have to set the value of the "IK-FK" property to 1.0, values in between transition between IK and FK during the animation.

[image]

You can also align FK bones to IK bones directly with "FK->IK" button and conversely you can also align IK bones to FK bones with "IK -> FK" button

[image]

Comment: Is there a problem if it's not aligned?

Comment: No, there is no problem if they are not aligned, their position depends on the animation you want to achieve and work with the value between IK and FK accordingly.